# Change PreferenceFragmentCompat dialog background color in Android

Tags: java, android, material-design, android-theme, preferenceactivity

I recently started working with **PreferenceFragmentCompat** and **MaterialComponents** and noticed that *in Dark mode*, Dialogs generated by preferences like **ListPreference** always have that weird grey android background no matter how many background attributes I change in the style.

[image: Image of the weird color (at the left)]
<sub>(source: [pocketnow.com](https://pocketnow.com/files/2015/09/android-marshmallow-dark-theme.jpg))</sub>

This I've tried:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
<item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
<item name="android:colorBackgroundFloating">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
```

I've also tried with **android:background** and worked but it brokes everything.

So I investigated a bit in-depth at elements like **EditTextPreferenceDialogFragment** and most of them create and show an AlertDialog instance [in the same function of PreferenceDialogFragment](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/6904f67/v14/preference/src/android/support/v14/preference/PreferenceDialogFragment.java#64) without any possibility to change its style.

Or at least that's the conclusion I've come to after some research on the subject.

My question is, has anyone found a workaround for this? Am I doing something wrong? Cause I would like to have those dialogs matching my app theme even if it's just the background color.

Btw, sorry if it has been already answered before. I also searched in here but found nothing and similar answers for different problems without results. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! After reading more the **AndroidX** package found that by default the **AlertDialog.Builder** retrieves a default theme from an attribute when no specified in the constructor. [You can see it here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/appcompat/appcompat/src/main/java/androidx/appcompat/app/AlertDialog.java#115)

So a solution would be to add a specific theme for dialogs in the activity like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogCustom</item>
</style>
```

And then you setup your dialog theme like:

```
<style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#FFC107</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:background">#4CAF50</item>
</style>
```

And this is the result:

[image: Fully changed dialog theme]

> Bonus tip: If you want to also setup the default theme for
> **MaterialAlertDialogBuilder** you must change de attribute
> **materialAlertDialogTheme**